# How to write sql code with fastcrud?

Tags: dapper-fastcrud

classes:

```
[Table("department_types", Schema = "public")]
public class DepartmentTypes


[Table("departments", Schema = "public")]
    public class Department
```

query:

```
private string BuildQuery()
            {
                return OrmConfiguration.GetSqlBuilder<DepartmentViewModel>().Format(
                    $@" SELECT {nameof(Department.Id):C},
                                {nameof(Department.Name):C},
                                {nameof(Department.TypeId):C},
                                {nameof(DepartmentTypes.Name):C} as DepartmentTypeName
                        FROM {nameof(Department):T}
                        LEFT JOIN {nameof(DepartmentTypes):T}
                        ON {nameof(Department.TypeId):C} = {nameof(DepartmentTypes.Id):C}");
            }
```

result class:

```
public class DepartmentViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int TypeId { get; set; }

        public string DepartmentTypeName { get; set; }

    }
```

I want to make a join with Department and DepartmentTypes and get a DepartmentViewModel result...

Now instead of `{nameof(DepartmentTypes):T}` (for example) system puts "DepartmentViewModel", not the name of DepartmentTypes which is: "department_types"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer :D.

```cs
private string BuildDepartmentListQuery()
            {
                var departmentTypeTable = Sql.Table<DepartmentType>();
                var departmentTable = Sql.Table<Department>();

                var departmentColumnId = Sql.TableAndColumn<Department>(nameof(Department.Id));
                var departmentColumnName = Sql.TableAndColumn<Department>(nameof(Department.Name));
                var departmentColumnTypeId = Sql.TableAndColumn<Department>(nameof(Department.TypeId));
                var departmentColumnManagerId = Sql.TableAndColumn<Department>(nameof(Department.ManagerId));

                var departmentTypeColumnId = Sql.TableAndColumn<DepartmentType>(nameof(DepartmentType.Id));
                var departmentTypeColumnName = Sql.TableAndColumn<DepartmentType>(nameof(DepartmentType.Name));

                string sqlBuilderResult = OrmConfiguration.GetSqlBuilder<Department>()
                    .Format(
                        $@"SELECT
      {departmentColumnId}
    , {departmentColumnName}
    , {departmentColumnTypeId}
    , {departmentColumnManagerId}
    , {departmentTypeColumnName} as ""DepartmentTypeName""
    FROM {departmentTable}
    LEFT JOIN {departmentTypeTable}
    ON {departmentColumnTypeId} = {departmentTypeColumnId}");
                ;

                return sqlBuilderResult;
    }
```

Comment: If it would be easier, I tried it your way and then just did it where I created my own string interpolated raw SQL query.  As long as you have proper table identifiers tied to your columns, it will still work.  In addition, since you are declaring <Department> as your entity, you can use the :T and :C items to shortcut some of your table/column declarations.